# Estabelecer pelo menos um número no EditText

Tags: java, android, null

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Existe alguma maneira de impedir o click de um botão caso um EditText não possua número nenhum? Consegui limitar valores mínimos e máximos (0 a 255), porém não consegui encontrar solução para esse problema. Pelo fato de "" não ser um valor  inteiro, ao clicar no botão sem preencher os três campos com algum número, o app crasha.

Tentei utilizar esse meio, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
btnCalc.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {   
                    if (edtRed == null || edtGreen == null || edtBlue == null)
                    {
                        btnCalc.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btnCalc.setEnabled(true);
                        getCode();
                    }
                    if (n1 > 255 || n1 < 0 || n2 > 255 || n2 < 0 || n3 > 255 || n3 < 0)
                    {
                        result = "#FFFFFF";
                        txtResult.setText(result);
                    }
                    else
                    {           
                        Calculate();
                    }   
                    result = "#" + rst1 + remainderR + rst2 + remainderG + rst3 + remainderB;
                    txtResult.setText(result);
                }               
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teste o tamanho do conteúdo do EditText no listener que indica que houve mudança nele, se o tamanho do conteúdo do seu EditText for maior que zero habilite o botão, caso contrário, desabilite.

Como o próprio autor da pergunta observou, o botão deve ser inicializado já desabilitado, pois o EditText começa vazio. Ele pode ser desabilitado tanto no xml quanto no código.

Exemplo:

```
btnOk = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
btnOk.setEnabled(false); //já inicia desabilitado
txtQuantidade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQuantidade);
txtQuantidade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(txtQuantidade.length() > 0 ) { //verifica tamanho do conteúdo do EditText
            btnOk.setEnabled(true);       //habilita botão
        }
        else {
            btnOk.setEnabled(false);      //desabilita botão
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Seu conteúdo sempre será um número, pois como você mesmo disse seu EditText aceita apenas números:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtQuantidade"
    android:inputType="number" //aceita apenas números
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Isso eu já fiz. Minha dúvida não é sobre limitar apenas números, e sim limitar uma quantidade mínima de algarismos antes do botão ser "habilitado", visto que a variável int que recebe o valor dos EditText não o aceita vazio.

Comment: @LeonardoSaldanha você quer que ao ter pelo menos um número ele mude o estado de um botão?

Comment: Não tem como não ser um número. Eu defini o inputType, então o certo seria receber apenas números, não é?

Comment: @LeonardoSaldanha vc está coberto de razao, rs

Comment: Então, eu só precisava encontrar uma maneira da variável que recebe esses valores, ver o "" como um número que ultrapasse o limite de 255, ou então que apenas não aceitasse, caso qualquer um dos três EditText estivesse vazio.

Comment: Pois é, @Math! Já até excluí a resposta :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn poderia ter tentado consertar, só avisei para não ganhar votos contra de bobeira

Comment: Valeu pelo toque, @Math! Mas estou meio trabalhando/meio olhando aqui. Quando fui ver, já era tarde, você já tinha respondido ;)

Comment: @Math , testei esse código e encontrei uma exceção. Caso o texto não seja alterado, o botão continuará habilitado até que algo seja digitado. Ou seja, se alguém simplesmente inicializar o aplicativo e clicar no botão, o crash acontecerá como se não tivesse esse trecho.

Comment: @LeonardoSaldanha é vdd, o botão tem que começar desabilitado desde o início, vou consertar no meu código

Comment: Portanto como solução, optei por colocar a configuração inicial do botão como desabilitado.

Comment: Exato! hahahaha

Comment: Deu certinho, valeu!

Comment: @Math, tem um detalhe que acabei de perceber. No caso de mais de um EditText, caso apenas um seja preenchido, o botão é habilitado da mesma forma, portanto é preciso utilizar uma função "E" após "txtQuantidade.length() > 0" para adicionar uma condição para outro Edit.